# kde5 reset user settings

Tags: kubuntu, settings, kde5

I'm confused. 
I was playing with opacity in KDE5 and made a mistake so now I can't see any windows at all -- ok, not one of my better moves :)

So I log out, and:

- rm -rf ~/.kde
- rm -rf ~/.local/share/kde* ; rm -rf ~/.local/share/plasma*
- rm -rf ~/.config/kde* ; rm -rf ~/.config/plasma*
- rm -rf ~/.local/share/compiz*; rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/
- rm -rf ~/local/share/kscreen* (don't even know what that one is)
- rm -rf .cache/compizconfig-1/

then re-login and KDE still has my old, can't-see-the-windows settings. 
I log into Unity or Fluxbox and it looks great .
I create another user account, log in with that and KDE looks fine.

So, somewhere KDE (or maybe X? or compiz?) is putting some user setting that I don't see. 
Any ideas where ?

Thanks for any help
--kevin